# how do you diagonalise this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Diagonalise $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\0  & 2\end{pmatrix}$. The characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^2$ hence there's only one eigenvalue that is $2$.

Comment: Are you sure it is diagonalizible?

Comment: Your matrix's already in Jordan Canonical Form, so it can't be diagonalized. Another way to see this is to observe that its minimal polynmomial is **not** the product of different linear factors.

Comment: If all eigenvalues are equal, then either the matrix is already diagonal, or it is not diagonalisable. Show this as a simple exercise :)

Comment: @MårtenW without using that a matrix is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial a product of distinct factors how would one prove it ?

Comment: @Grobber Would you be so kind to post an answer containing the results, so that the question doesn't remain unanswered ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Compute the eigen space for the eigen value $2$.

Comment: @kan Here it is an easy computation, but in the general case I don't see it via the eigenspaces

Comment: In the general case too, the same argument works.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Assume $A=SDS^{-1}$. If all eigenvalues are equal (say, equal to $\lambda$), then $D = \lambda I$, and hence $A = \lambda I$.

Comment: @MårtenW oh right it commutes thanks

Comment: In case this is of interest here: I just added a question for the case of infinite size. see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459454/with-infinite-size-we-can-have-p-cdot-m-m-cdot-d-d-diagonal-where-m

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. My solution goes as follows. Thanks to the comments.
Let $A$ be a matrix with characteristic polynomial $(x-\lambda)^n$. Then it is diagonalisable iff $A=\lambda I$.

Suppose on the contrary it is similar to a non-scalar diagonalisable matrix. Then clearly characteristic polynomial is different. Hence we are done.

In my case we see its not a scalar matrix. So, not diagonalisable.

Answer (score 0):

You should also note that your matrix is currently in its Jordan Canonical Form, so it wouldn't be possible to diagonalise this matrix.

[Jordan Canonical Form wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)