# With infinite size, we can have $P \cdot M = M \cdot D $ (D diagonal) but where $M^{-1}$ does not exist. Can we say "P is diagonalizable"?

Tags: matrices, terminology, definition, diagonalization, infinite-matrices

*(I had this question in mind for longer time, but it is just triggered now by some comments at that [recent question in mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459400/how-do-you-diagonalise-this-matrix))*

***(Background)*** I was looking at properties of the Pascal-matrix:

$\qquad \qquad  P_{n=5}=\small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 . & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
 . & . & 1 & 3 & 6 \\ 
 . & . & . & 1 & 4 \\ 
 . & . & . & . & 1
 \end{bmatrix} $  where the index $n$ indicates  the size of the matrix.

This matrix, for any size *n x n* is not diagonalizable. However, in the case of infinite size we can have 
$$ \lim_{ n\to \infty} P_n \cdot M_n = M_n \cdot D_n $$ or simply $$ P \cdot M = M \cdot D \qquad \qquad \text{matrices of infinite size}$$(D diagonal) with some matrix $M$ (see below) but where we cannot write $ P = M \cdot D \cdot M^{-1}$ because $M^{-1}$ does not exist for that case of infinite size.

*(M has the form $M :m_{r,c} = { c^r \over r!} \qquad \small \text{where } r,c \ge 0 $)*

***Question:*** Can I thus write in an article: *"P when assumed of infinite size is diagonalizable"* ?
Or would there be another (canonical) expression/terminology for this?

---

*Appendix 1*
The top left *5x5* segment of the infinite matrix $M$ is $ \displaystyle M = \Tiny \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots \\ 
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots  \\ 
 0 & 1/2 & 2 & 9/2 & 8  & \cdots \\ 
 0 & 1/6 & 4/3 & 9/2 & 32/3  & \cdots \\ 
 0 & 1/24 & 2/3 & 27/8 & 32/3 & \cdots \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
 \end{bmatrix}$

The infinite matrix $D$ is $ \displaystyle diag([1,e,e^2,e^3,e^4,...])$

---

*Appendix 2*
*(If we introduce a symbol $ \# $ for a formal notation of matrix-multiplication, but where the evaluation is not allowed due to divergence/singularity in the dot-products we can write a nearly perfect diagonalization formula with all triangular invertible matrices $$ P = (S_2 \cdot P) \cdot D \cdot (P^{-1} \# S_1) \\ P^m = (S_2 \cdot P) \cdot D^m \cdot (P^{-1} \# S_1)$$ where the matrices $S_2$ and $S_1$ are the arrays of Stirling numbers second resp first kind, scaled by factorials and $S_1 = S_2^{-1}$ also in the case of infinite size (as mentioned for instance in Abramowicz&Stegun))*

Comment: You're saying $$\lim_{ n\to \infty} P_n \cdot M_n =\lim_{ n\to \infty} M_n \cdot D_n$$ yes? But what is $M_n$?

Comment: @Peter: I thought the definition in the question was sufficient; I'll add an explicite truncation there.

Comment: @Peter: ahh, I see. The index $\ _n$ indicates the size, and if omitted, means infinite size.